Executing Simics Commands via Shell Script
I want to use simics via a shell script
I mean what I am actually wanting to see if there is a way to run simics like this:
simics file.ext

where file.ext is a file which has the commands that i can execute
Or if I could just write a bash shell script to do it
I have a proj. in my mind but i need to execute shell commands in the target system just like we can do it in Docker
I mean I f you have used docker there is this cmd:
docker exec <container name>  <command> where I can execute a command in the target system without actually entering into the system console
I want to do a similar thing using simics
Doing an ssh into the target system is one way but otherwise is there anything else??
Clarifying Comment that Deserves to be in the Question
i guess i did not frame the question clear enough. Let me try this again. Imagine I send a command lets say "ls" to the target OS and now depending o the the answer I receive from the target OS lets say it having N number of files i want to determine the next step , dynamically in the host OS . Is there a way to do this?

The answer to the second question is also yes.  Use scripting in Simics to send inputs to the target and retrieve the output, and then make selections about what to do.
Specifically, you can use the "record" function of the serial console to retrieve a chunk of output from the console, and then you can parse it using either CLI or Python.
The logic is typically:

Send input to target
Wait for newline or something to note that the target OS took the command
Do record-start on the console object
Wait for end of the output using some appropriate pattern
Do $x = CONSOLEOBJECT.record-stop
Parse out the contents of the CLI variable

Like in:
$con = ...
$con.input "cmd\n"
bp.console_string.wait-for $con "\n"  ## Wait for newline to echo
$con.record-start
bp.console_string.wait-for $con "end of interesting output"
$output = $con.record-stop
## look at $output 


since you mention using the python cli can you please guide me on how to get python3 connected to simics
is there something like pip install simics ?

No, you run it inside of simics. You start simics and then run Python code and CLI code inside the simics process.  No need to install anything.

Start simics and go through the tutorials to learn to use the CLI interactively.

I have used the interactive cli,  I just wanted to see how to run the python scripts ,. Anyways thank you. I understood what you mean, I will try it later

Use 'run-python-file' to run Python from a file

The standard way for Simics is to put the CLI commands in a file ending in .simics.  Then you can do:
$ ./simics myscript.simics

To run Simics with that command file.
But it sounds like you ask how to send inputs to the target console of the simulated target machine?  In that case, the easiest way is to use script branches in the Simics script.
There are many examples of this in the Simics documentation and in the training package.
Remeber that a Simics setup can contain many target machines in a network; and each can have many consoles.  There is no way for Simics to send things "to the target" as that can be anyway.  Sometimes a serial port, sometimes a graphics console... sometimes multiple serial ports to differnt parts of the same hardware.
Docker is addressing a super-narrow very specialized case.

i guess i did not frame the question clear enough.
Let me try this again.
Imagine I send a command lets say "ls" to the target OS and now depending o the the answer I receive from the target OS lets say it having N number of files i want to determine the next step , dynamically in the host OS .
Is there a way to do this?
